# Subtracting/Adding to a Where clause timestamp condition

Tags: oracle, datetime, plsql

I'm attempting to speed up a timestamp comparison query by restricting the query to 30 minutes before and after the timestamp in question. This is the format I'm using:

```
Causedat
-----
11-NOV-15 10.20.58.000000000 AM
11-NOV-15 10.19.41.877000000 AM
10-NOV-15 11.01.40.000000000 AM
10-NOV-15 11.00.50.460000000 AM
05-NOV-15 01.53.30.966000000 PM
05-NOV-15 01.47.31.000000000 PM
```

What I'm trying to do is write a condition where i'll tell the system only to look for dates in the system that are +-00:30:00.000000000 (thirty minutes) from the Causedat date in the future or past from that time.

I've seen that for example, `SYSDATE - SYSTIMESTAMP` is a legitimate calculation. Is it possible to do something similar to this like this:

```
WHERE search.date >= (Causedat = Causedat - '000000000 00:30:00.000000000')
AND   search.date <= (Causedat = Causedat + '000000000 00:30:00.000000000')
```

Please assume the date i'm searching and Causedat are in the same (timestamp) format for this question.

Thank you for any light you may be able to shine on the problem for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an interval to a timestamp; [you can read about datetime and interval arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208). There are conversion functions to go from a variable to an interval, but with known fixed values you can use [an interval literal](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00221) here. You can use the full string you have:

```
where search_date >= causedat - interval '000000000 00:30:00.000000000' day to second
and   search_date <= causedat + interval '000000000 00:30:00.000000000' day to second;
```

Or just the non-zero part:

```
where search_date >= causedat - interval '30' minute
and   search_date <= causedat + interval '30' minute;
```

Trivial demo of how these evaluate:

```
select systimestamp,
  systimestamp - interval '000000000 00:30:00.000000000' day to second as minus_30,
  systimestamp + interval '000000000 00:30:00.000000000' day to second as plus_30
from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP                        MINUS_30                            PLUS_30                           
----------------------------------- ----------------------------------- -----------------------------------
18-NOV-15 11.39.09.597473000 +00:00 18-NOV-15 11.09.09.597473000 +00:00 18-NOV-15 12.09.09.597473000 +00:00

select systimestamp,
  systimestamp - interval '30' minute as minus_30,
  systimestamp + interval '30' minute as plus_30
from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP                        MINUS_30                            PLUS_30                           
----------------------------------- ----------------------------------- -----------------------------------
18-NOV-15 11.39.09.653809000 +00:00 18-NOV-15 11.09.09.653809000 +00:00 18-NOV-15 12.09.09.653809000 +00:00
```

Comment: Thank you for the specific and expansive solution to my problem. I've accepted it as awnsered.

Answer (score 1):

Direct arithmetic on date time column with required interval value.

```
WHERE search.date
      BETWEEN Causedat - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
          AND Causedat + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
```

Comment: You've linked to MySQL documentation. Oracle RDBMS doesn't have DATE_ADD or DATE_SUB.

Comment: ***@AlexPoole***: I think [`TO_DSINTERVAL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions184.htm#i1014645) should work

Comment: @RavinderReddy - if you have a variable value then yes; but in this case with a fixed value literals are fine. (Your second version would work in Oracle if you put the 30 in single quotes to make it a literal).

Comment: You still need `'30'` rather than the unquoted `30`. It has to be a literal [as shown in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00221); the single quotes are not optional.

Comment: Also, Its minute, not minutes.

Comment: Yes, I observed it just after my edit. But did not change it again. Made it now.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the question. I have provided a simple example to illustrate how we can achieve this.

```
SELECT A.DT
FROM
  ( SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '60' MINUTE AS DT FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE AS DT FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AS DT FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE AS DT FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '60' MINUTE AS DT FROM DUAL
  )A
WHERE A.DT BETWEEN (SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE) AND (SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE);
```

Let me know if this helps.